# Concat List<type> where lists can be null

Tags: c#

I have three lists

```
List<Project> intProjects = ProjectRepo.GetAllInternalProjects();
List<Project> extProjects = ProjectRepo.GetAllExternalProjects();
List<Project> mgmProjects = ProjectRepo.GetAllManagementProjects();
List<Project> projects = intProjects.Concat(extProjects).Concat(mgmProjects).ToList();
```

If i have items in all of the lists it works fine, but i am receiving a `null value` exception when one of the lists is `null`.

Yes, i could do a

```
if (extProjects != null && mgmpProjects != null && intProjects != null)
    ...
else if (extProjects == null && mgmpProjects != null && intProjects != null
    ...
```

for all possible cases, but there must be a more effective way join lists even if they are null.

So my question is: How can i concat lists where lists can be null without getting an error?

Comment: Use Concat(extProjects ?? new List<Project>())

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this using the `??` operator:

```
List<Project> empty = new List<Project>();
List<Project> intProjects = ProjectRepo.GetAllInternalProjects() ?? empty;
List<Project> extProjects = ProjectRepo.GetAllExternalProjects() ?? empty;
List<Project> mgmProjects = ProjectRepo.GetAllManagementProjects() ?? empty;
List<Project> projects = intProjects.Concat(extProjects).Concat(mgmProjects).ToList();
```

[?? Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

Comment: `Enumerable.Empty<Project>()` would reflect the intention better.

Answer (score 5):

You could use an extension method like this

```
public static class EnumerableExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> ConcatOrSkipNull<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second)
    {
        if (first == null)
           first = new List<TSource>();
        if (second == null)
            return first;
        return first.Concat(second);
    }
}
```

and rewrite your code then to:

```
 var projects = intProjects
                  .ConcatOrSkipNull(extProjects)
                  .ConcatOrSkipNull(mgmProjects)
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: Great idea! I would suggest two minor changes: (1) Skip the `first == null` check. Just make it part of the method's contract that its operation is undefined if called with a null reference for the `this` parameter. (2) Not sure if `ConcatOrDefault` is a good name. With LINQ, `…OrDefault` usually means that `null` might be returned, which is not the case here. How about `ConcatOrSource`, `ConcatOrOriginal`, `ConcatOrSelf`, etc.

Comment: @stakx - Thanks for your thoughts. I have included the ´first == null´ check, because of the OP's stated problem. Regarding (2): Naming is really a tough task. Now I came up with ´ConcatOrSkipNull´. But I think there is still a better naming possible...

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily efficient, but doesn't require much typing:

```
List<Project> projects = new[] { intProjects, extProjects, mgmProjects }
                         .Where(list => list != null)
                         .SelectMany(_ => _)
                         .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your ProjectRepo make sure the functions `GetAllInternalProjects()`, `GetAllExternalProjects()`, `GetAllManagementProjects()` all return an empty list if no results are found. For functions that return lists, I initialize the return value at the beginning of the function, then do something to that list if needed, and always return that value. That way the function will always return a list object, empty or non-empty. That should clean up your code.

An example below:

```
List<object> GetAllInternalProjects(){
    List<object> results = new List<object>();

    /do something here

    return results;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is an extension method like

```
  public static partial class EnumerableExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<T> EmptyIfNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) {
      return source ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }
  }
```

So you can put

```
  List<Project> projects = intProjects
    .EmptyIfNull()
    .Concat(extProjects.EmptyIfNull())
    .Concat(mgmProjects.EmptyIfNull())
    .ToList();
```

A better approach is modifing `GetAllInternalProjects()`, `GetAllExternalProjects()` and `ProjectRepo.GetAllManagementProjects()` methods: these methods must always return *not* `null` collection (which can be *empty*, however)